# Old lady who had the (a) Green Lantern ring

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification, green-lantern

No I am not making this up, at a point in the 80's I had a DC comic (rather thick for a comic book), one of the stories in it featured an old, grey-haired woman who had a Green Lantern ring and the powers that come with it. The villains of the story had her trapped in a yellow bubble, which she escaped from by popping it with a needle she created with her ring. If it helps with identification, the comic also had a rather bleak Superman story where (I think) the Man of Steel imagines a nuclear war he was unable to prevent.

Comment: Was KT21 the character you were thinking of?

Comment: @LogicDictates- I'm not sure- all this time I thought the character I saw was human, and in the grandparent age range- also the memory of her using a needle is particularly vivid.

Comment: Does the cover of _[Superman Vol. 1 #408](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_408)_ ring a bell? Because I suspect that's the issue the Superman story you described came from. That issue was published in June 1985, and I found the Green Lantern issue (which was published in April 1985) by using that publication date as a guide. I figured that if two stories were reprinted in the same collection, they were likely to have been originally published around the same time.

Comment: Also, it seems highly unlikely that a needle created by a GL ring could've been used to pop a yellow sphere, since GL rings didn't work against anything yellow back in the 1980s. That's why KT21 had to inflate a red plastiglass bubble within the yellow sphere, so she could strike a red surface instead of a yellow one. GL rings retained this deficiency until [Kyle Rayner](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kyle_Rayner_(New_Earth)) became Green Lantern in 1994.

Answer (score 15):

You're almost certainly thinking of ***[KT21](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/KT21_(New_Earth))***.

She was an alien member of the Green Lantern Corps, hailing from the planet Jerome, and made her first appearance in *[Green Lantern Vol. 2 #187](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Vol_2_187)* (April 1985), which contains a scene very similar to the one you described.

As you stated, she was trapped in a yellow sphere, and escaped not by projecting a needle construct with her Green Power Ring (since Green Power Rings couldn't directly affect anything yellow back in the '80s), but rather by inflating a bubble of red plastiglass within the yellow sphere, and then striking it with a hammer construct hard enough to shatter both.

The story was titled "Forever Blowing Bubbles!".

Incidentally, the Superman story you described was likely from *[Superman Vol. 1 #408](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_408)*. It did help with the search, as I managed to ID the Superman issue first, and then used the publication date of that issue (June 1985) as a guide to when the Green Lantern story was likely to have been published.

[image]

[image]